# Randomizing blocks with non-identical probabilities in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I am designing an experiment in Qualtrics with several treatments and one control group. There are three scenarios in the experiment, and every scenario has several treatments. I have constructed the survey so that every scenario corresponds to one block, and the treatments are then administered as randomly assigned question (with only descriptive text) within the blocks.

This works well, except for the fact that I want to make sure that individuals who are assigned to the control group only get the control in all three scenarios. My initial solution to this problem was to create a control block, in addition to the three scenario blocks where treatments are administered. However, since Qualtrics randomizes with even probabilities across blocks, this would lead to 1/4 of the participants being assigned the control scenario. Ideally, I would like to assign 1/10 of the respondents to the control group, since my most interesting comparisons for this experiment is across different treatment groups. The control is there simply to serve as a benchmark.

Is there any way to randomly assign respondents to different blocks with different probabilities?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be to duplicate blocks in your randomizer multiple times. Since you are only showing 1 block to a respondent, this would have the effect of increasing the chances of particular blocks being chosen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm quite reluctant to use this solution since I have a lot of treatments, and the more blocks I would need to create and customise the higher the probability is that a typo (or something worse) will occur, interfering with the treatment.

I got another suggestion to use the random number generator, and then branch based on a certain number. What do you think of this approach?

Comment: I think that branching based on a random number is reasonable as well.